# What is the criteria of safek pikuach nefesh?

Tags: halacha-theory, medicine, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, contemporary-halacha, danger

An expert in a particular field (a doctor, an actuary, etc.) can advise on the risk of mortality from a specific activity of anywhere between 0% and 100%. At what threshold of risk would the halacha determine whether a particular activity constitutes *safek pikuach nefesh?*

When experts disagree, would the halacha look at the opinion of a single expert, a simple majority of experts, or another criterion to determine the correct opinion to rely on?

Comment: Note it doesn't just have to be a one specific number in all cases. It could be the number is different if it's a danger commonly taken seriously or a danger that's imminent or a danger that applies to a specific group or something else.

Comment: Double AA - you are probably alluding to the fact that some risks fall under the concept of shomer pesaim Hashem - that question is here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114750/what-are-the-parameters-of-shomer-pesaim-hashem

Comment: Partially, and realize it's "pesayim" the yud is pronounced and the alef is silent

Comment: Is safek pikuach nefesh the same as safek sakana?

Comment: cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66775/170